# Laravel controller validation Request does not exist

Tags: function, validation, request, unique, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 validation, and what i'm trying to do is to validate a form with some input **name**, unique to table Sizes column "name" where it also depends on another column **speciesId** that the value from $request->speciesId.

The function in Controller is looks like this

```
    public function storeSize(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate(
            [
                'name' => [
                    'required', Rule::unique('sizes')->where(function ($query) {
                        return $query->where('speciesId', $request->speciesId);
                    })
                ],
                'speciesId' => 'required'
            ]
        );
    }
```

already add **use Illuminate\Http\Request;** and **use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;** but still got "ErrorException Undefined variable: request".

when i'm try to var_dump($request) or echo $request->speciesID, the variable and value is present.

my question is, why the validation function doesn't recognize the Request variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because inside your `function` call `$request` is not available. You need to make it available by adding `use $request` to `function ($query)`:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
  'name' => [
    'required', Rule::unique('sizes')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
       return $query->where('speciesId', $request->speciesId);
     })
  ],
  'speciesId' => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @brombeer, finally the $request is recognized. 

the validation is still not working tho, but thats another question.

Comment: My Bad, wrong data input. Your answer is work like a charm, thanks @brombeer